# Radio Signal Stationarity

Tags: statistics, stationary, software-defined-radio, communication-standard

A radio signal recording of a wireless communication system (e.g: Wi-Fi traffic) is beaconized, channelized and subject to noise.

- When working with such an RF signal, numerically transformed to a stochastic timeseries, to which extent can I consider the signal to be stationary?
- What properties are relevant from a communications point of view?

Comment: Any pointer papers about signal stationarity in telecommunications are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> When working with such an RF signal, numerically transformed to a stochastic timeseries, to which extent can I consider the signal to be stationary?

That depends on your signal model. We can't tell you that – but for example, in time-slotted system, obviously the received signal can't be stationary – its variance (which is basically its power) depends on the time you're looking at.

We tend to model noise as (weak-sense) stationary; same for data coming out of the source coding; we often even technically enforce that using *whitening* scramblers.

However, that *really* depends: some systems use whitening. Others don't.

Some techniques assume all disturbances to be stationary. Others are built around the specific notion that interference is not stationary.

So, *model* your signal.

> Any pointer papers about signal stationarity in telecommunications are appreciated.

Not an issue for papers: this is subject for standard textbook discussion; Goldsmith and Viswanath/Tse would be my go-to books here.

(Generally, if you feel like something is so important that it is a basis for all that you do, it's almost certain people have looked at it a long time ago and have already written a good book on it. The trick is finding the good books; in this case, things are so fundamental that basically all wireless communication books concern themselves with it.)

> What properties are relevant from a communications point of view?

All and none. Defined in the signal model.